# Python irregularly shaped image warping to circle

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I want to take an irregular shaped png image with a transparent background, and warp it to a circle.

Context: The image will have to be projected on the outside of a half sphere later, and fully making it fill a circle by stretching it seemed like a good first step.

The image below shows the two steps I would take for this:

[image: steps]

My plan of attack was as follows:

1. Resize image to square
2. Get the contour of the image as a np array
3. Create a circle with the same diameter as the image, and the same amount of points as the contour
4. Get the transformation matrix using findHomography
5. Warp the source image using this matrix

```py
def image_to_circle(filename: str):
    source_image = cv2.imread(filename)
    source_gray = cv2.cvtColor(source_image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    # resize image and grayscale image to a square
    height, width = source_gray.shape
    dimension = min(width, height)
    source_image = cv2.resize(source_image, (dimension, dimension))
    source_gray = cv2.resize(source_gray, (dimension, dimension))

    # find the source contour
    contours, _ = cv2.findContours(
        source_gray, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE
    )
    source_contour = max(contours, key=cv2.contourArea)

    radius = dimension / 2
    target_contour = generate_circle_points(radius, len(source_contour))

    # compute the perspective transformation matrix
    homography_matrix, _ = cv2.findHomography(source_contour, target_contour)

    # warp the source image to the destination based on the homography matrix
    warped_image = cv2.warpPerspective(
        source_image, homography_matrix, (dimension, dimension)
    )

    cv2.imwrite("warped-" + filename, warped_image)
```

```py
def generate_circle_points(radius, num_points):
    angles = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, num_points)

    x = radius * np.cos(angles)
    y = radius * np.sin(angles)

    return np.column_stack((x, y))
```

However, this doesn't work, seeing as the input image:
[image: unwarped house]
results in this output:
[image: warped house]

I'm guessing that `warpPerspective` doesn't work in the same way I expected?

Comment: your presented transform isn't affine or perspective.

Comment: Good point, I don't really have a background on image transformations. 
I saw the perspective warp being used for what I thought were similar problems, so I tried that here.
Do you have any idea about what sort of transformation I can use for this?

Comment: do you want artistic effects (photoshop) or do you want to solve a specific physical/optical problem? for the latter, you failed to go into the required detail on your spherical projection

Comment: It's purely an artistic effect indeed. The only requirement is that the image is squished to fit in a circle shape, and looks as if it's wrapped around the visible side of a ball, without major parts of the image data disappearing (it's fine to have a distorted aspect ratio and distortion between parts of the image that get squished more/less)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how to warp a square image onto a sphere in Python/OpenCV.

- Read the input
- Get center coordinates and set radius
- Set up x, y and mask black arrays as floats
- For each x,y pixel in output image compute the inverse transformation to the input
- Apply remap to do the warping
- Apply the circular mask
- Save the results

Input:

[image]

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import math

img = cv2.imread("lena.jpg")

# set gain
gain = 1.5

# set background color
bgcolor = (0,0,0)

# get dimensions
h, w = img.shape[:2]
xcent = w / 2
ycent = h / 2
rad = min(xcent,ycent)

# set up the x and y maps as float32
map_x = np.zeros((h, w), np.float32)
map_y = np.zeros((h, w), np.float32)
mask = np.zeros((h, w), np.uint8)

# create map with the spherize distortion formula --- arcsin(r)
# xcomp = arcsin(r)*x/r; ycomp = arsin(r)*y/r
for y in range(h):
    Y = (y - ycent)/ycent
    for x in range(w):
        X = (x - xcent)/xcent
        R = math.hypot(X,Y)
        if R == 0:
            map_x[y, x] = x
            map_y[y, x] = y
            mask[y,x] = 255
        elif R > 1:
            map_x[y, x] = x
            map_y[y, x] = y
            mask[y,x] = 0
        elif gain >= 0:
            map_x[y, x] = xcent*X*math.pow((2/math.pi)*(math.asin(R)/R), gain) + xcent
            map_y[y, x] = ycent*Y*math.pow((2/math.pi)*(math.asin(R)/R), gain) + ycent
            mask[y,x] = 255
        elif gain < 0:
            gain2 = -gain
            map_x[y, x] = xcent*X*math.pow((math.sin(math.pi*R/2)/R), gain2) + xcent
            map_y[y, x] = ycent*Y*math.pow((math.sin(math.pi*R/2)/R), gain2) + ycent
            mask[y,x] = 255

# do the remap  this is where the magic happens
result = cv2.remap(img, map_x, map_y, cv2.INTER_LINEAR, borderMode = cv2.BORDER_REFLECT_101, borderValue=(0,0,0))

# process with mask
result2 = result.copy()
result2[mask==0] = bgcolor

# save results
cv2.imwrite("lena_spherize_A.jpg", result)
cv2.imwrite("lena_spherize_B.jpg", result2)

# display images
cv2.imshow('img', img)
cv2.imshow('result', result)
cv2.imshow('result2', result2)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Result Before Masking:

[image]

Result After Masking:

[image]

Note: Increasing the gain, increases the spherical distortion

Comment: Thanks  a lot for the detailed answer!  
I edited it a bit to get a transparant trim around the circle like so:  

```result = cv2.cvtColor(result, cv2.COLOR_BGR2BGRA)
result[:, :, 3] = mask```
for whoever's interested.  
  
Note that this answer is not fully what I was looking for, since it won't deal very well with irregular shapes (losing data instead of stretching it all to fit), but I'll build it like this and validate against the dataset I want to use it for if this is fine.

Comment: I do not think you will find a way to do that for irregular shapes. The best you can do is crop your image so that you cut off the irregular shapes and have a square region that comes from inside all the zig-zags. Then warp that to a circle.